# How to get specific fields from child serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, serialization

Say, there are two models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    r = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Model2(models.Model):
    p = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    m = models.ForeignKey(Model1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The serializers are :

```
class Model1Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'

class Model2Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Model2
         fields = '__all__'
```

The given Model1 serializer returns the output as:
    {
        "id": 1,
        "r": "r_value"
    }

and model 2 serializer output is:
    {
        "id":1,
        "p: "p_value",
        "m": 1
    }

The thing is that I also want the r value in the model2 serializer output. How to do that?

Comment: Please mark correct answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify new field with correct `source` - you can read more in [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source).

#### Option 1: With class **Serializer**:

```
class Model2Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    p = serializers.CharField()
    r = serializers.CharField(source='m.r')

    class Meta:
         model = Model2
         fields = '__all__'
```

Output: `{'p': u'pppp', 'r': u'rrrrr', 'id': 1}`

#### Option 2: With class **ModelSerializer**:

```
class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    r = serializers.CharField(source='m.r')

    class Meta:
         model = Model2
         fields = '__all__'
```

Output: `{'p': u'pppp', 'r': u'rrrrr', 'm': 1L, u'id': 1}`

#### Option 3: To include whole **Model1**:

```
class Model1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'

class Model2Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    m = Model1Serializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'
```

Output: `{'m': OrderedDict([(u'id', 1), ('r', u'rrrrr')])}`

Answer (score 1):

### 1. If you want r as attrs of m

*define Serializer class of specific Relational Field*

```py
class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    m = Model1Serializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "m": {
            "id": 1,
            "r": "RED"
        },
        "p": "Light RED"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "m": {
            "id": 1,
            "r": "RED"
        },
        "p": "Dark RED"
    }
]
```

### 2. If you want just r Using ReadOnlyField

*You can use ReadOnlyField*

```py
class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    r = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='m.r')

    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "r": "RED",
        "p": "Light RED",
        "m": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "r": "RED",
        "p": "Dark RED",
        "m": 1
    }
]
```

### 3. If you want just r Using SerializerMethodField()

*You can you SerializerMethodField and ist read only as well*

```py
class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    r = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_r(self, instance):
        return instance.m.r
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "r": "RED",
        "p": "Light RED",
        "m": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "r": "RED",
        "p": "Dark RED",
        "m": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Model1Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Model1
      fields = '__all__'

class Model2Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
  r = Model1Serializer(many=True, source="model1_set")
  class Meta:
     model = Model2
     fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

DRF makes it quite easy if you already have a `Model1Serializer` for Model1:

```
class Model2Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    m = Model1Serializer()
    class Meta:
         model = Model2
         fields = '__all__'
```

That should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `depth=1` in your serializer Meta. Like this:

```
class Model2Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Model2
         fields = '__all__'
         depth = 1
```

This will go for a level of 1 into the Foreign keys that do exist in that model. (**By the way,** I don't recommend it for big models. But it's perfectly suitable for your situation)